# Keras: learning rate schedule

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am implementing an MLP in Keras, and tweaking the hyperparameters. One object of experimentation is the learning rate. There are two schedules I'm trying to use, both outlined in [this tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/using-learning-rate-schedules-deep-learning-models-python-keras/). One is specifically defined using learning rate / epochs, and one uses a separately-defined step decay function. The necessary code is below.

The error is 'The output of the "schedule" function should be float'. I specifically cast the learning rate as a float, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: original code was not a MWE, I apologize. To reproduce this error, you can save the data snippets below and run this code.

```
import numpy as np
import sys, argparse, keras, string
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

def load_data(data_file, test_file):
    dataset = np.loadtxt(data_file, delimiter=",")

    # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
    X = dataset[:, 0:(dataset.shape[1]-2)]
    Y = dataset[:, dataset.shape[1]-1]
    Y = Y - 1

    testset = np.loadtxt(test_file, delimiter=",")

    X_test = testset[:, 0:(testset.shape[1]-2)]
    Y_test = testset[:, testset.shape[1]-1]
    Y_test = Y_test - 1

    return (X, Y, X_test, Y_test)

def mlp_keras(data_file, test_file, save_file, num_layers, num_units_per_layer, learning_rate_, epochs_, batch_size_):

        history = History()
        seed = 7
        np.random.seed(seed)

        X, y_binary, X_test, ytest = load_data(data_file, test_file)

        d1 = True

        ### create model  
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(num_units_per_layer[0], input_dim=X.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='relu', W_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(num_units_per_layer[1], init='uniform', activation = 'relu', W_constraint=maxnorm(3))) #W_constraint for dropout
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid')) 

        def step_decay(epoch):
                drop_every = 10
                decay_rate = (learning_rate_*np.power(0.5, np.floor((1+drop_every)/drop_every))).astype('float32')
                return decay_rate

        earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

        sgd = SGD(lr = 0.0, momentum = 0.8, decay = 0.0, nesterov=False)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
        if d1 == True:
                lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
        else:
                lrate = (learning_rate_/epochs).astype('float32')

        callbacks_list = [lrate, earlyStopping]

        ## Fit the model
        hist = model.fit(X, y_binary, validation_data=(X_test, ytest), nb_epoch=epochs_, batch_size=batch_size_, callbacks=callbacks_list) #48 batch_size, 2 epochs
        scores = model.evaluate(X, y_binary)
        print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
if __name__ == '__main__':

        m1 = mlp_keras('train_rows.csv', 'test_rows.csv', 'res1.csv', 2, [100, 100], 0.001,  10, 10)
```

Error message:

```
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 435, in on_epoch_begin
    assert type(lr) == float, 'The output of the "schedule" function should be float.'
AssertionError: The output of the "schedule" function should be float.
```

Data snippet (train_ex.csv):

```
1,21,38,33,20,8,8,6,4,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1,19,29,26,28,13,6,7,3,2,4,4,3,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1,22,21,22,15,11,12,9,4,6,4,5,4,2,1,0,4,1,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
1,18,24,14,17,6,14,10,5,7,4,2,4,1,4,2,0,3,4,1,3,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
```

Data snippet (test_ex.csv):

```
1,16,30,40,44,8,7,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1,19,32,16,18,32,5,7,4,6,1,1,0,2,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1,29,55,21,11,6,6,7,8,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
1,23,18,11,16,10,7,5,7,9,3,7,8,5,3,4,0,3,3,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
```

EDIT 2:

Based on @sascha's comments, I've tried modifying a bit (this is the relevant section below). Same error.

```
def step_decay(epoch):
        drop_every = 10
        decay_rate = (learning_rate_*np.power(0.5, np.floor((1+drop_every)/drop_every))).astype('float32')
        return decay_rate

def step_exp_decay(epoch):
        return (learning_rate_/epochs).astype('float32')

earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

sgd = SGD(lr = 0.0, momentum = 0.8, decay = 0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
if d1 == True:
        lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
else:   
        lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_exp_decay)
```

Comment: ```lr = 0.0``` makes no sense at all. ```decay=0.0``` is also very bad. Do you understand the basics of NN-learning? (only judging the code here)

Comment: Good question - that was done in the tutorial I linked to. It made no sense to me either, but I'm no expert. Have a look under the section 'Drop-Based Learning Rate Schedule'.

Comment: I see. He is overwriting this with his callback. But his callback is calling a function. Your's is not. It's more of a basic python-programming problem!

Comment: Thank you, do you know how exactly?

Comment: In his callback list ```lrate```is executed, it's a function. In your callback, ```lrate``` is a variable. The function setting it up is not called (because the function name is not part of the callback-list; therefore your learning_rate is still 0; same for decay). I highly recommend a bit of python research! (the basic problem is your renaming of various stuff; but make sure you understand the code!)

Comment: Thank you @sascha, much appreciated. I definitely have a lot to learn. If you have a moment and wouldn't mind writing an answer, I'd be happy to accept it if it works!

Comment: I can't convert it to an answer atm. But be sure: that's the problem! I'm positive you can modify your code to reflect his ideas! Just evaluate what his callbacks are doing and what yours are doing!

Comment: Your edit is pointless and does not adress what i explained. Where is the callback there?

Comment: Clearly I am misunderstanding. I made an honest attempt, I don't understand what you're looking for. Could you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 8):

You can also try to check out the [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau) callback to reduce the learning rate by a pre-defined factor, if a monitored value has not changed for a certain number of epochs, e.g. half the learning rate if the validation accuracy has not improved for five epochs looks like this:

```
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', 
                                            patience=5, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.0001)
model.fit_generator(..., callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction], ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **i misinterpreted your code earlier and my comments are deprecated! Sorry!**.

The error-message leads us to the real problem here!

You define your scheduler like this:

```
def step_decay(epoch):
    drop_every = 10
    decay_rate = (learning_rate_*np.power(0.5, np.floor((1+drop_every)/drop_every))).astype('float32')
    return decay_rate
```

**Check the type it returns!*** It's `<class 'numpy.float32'>`. (Try it: with python's `type()` function)

Somehow keras is not doing a very general check for these types and expects `<class 'float'>` (python's native float).

Just convert your numpy-float to a native python-float:

Replace: `decay_rate = (learning_rate_*np.power(0.5, np.floor((1+drop_every)/drop_every))).astype('float32')`

with: `decay_rate = (learning_rate_*np.power(0.5, np.floor((1+drop_every)/drop_every))).astype('float32').item()`

[Read the docs of numpy.ndarray.item](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) (especially the notes on the why of this behaviour)

The blog-author does not have this problem as he is not using numpy within his scheduler and uses python's math-functions. This will result in a native-float!